# Matching text to named range and returning named range approximate match

Tags: excel, match

Looking to figure out how to automate a Model Number matching search and return.

Searching an "Order Report"(sheet1) cell that when the value is partially reduced will be a match for a model value where the range is named (model_list) and my goal is to return that match.

Example

Sheet 1 cell A3 is the location of the Order Report model number
ex: 12-TH512-100E

Sheet 3 range G3:G100 is the named range "model_list" 
ex: TH510, TH512, TH514, TH516, TH518, TH520

Use a formula in Sheet 2 to find the model_list match and return its value
ex: TH512

My only attempts and research so far has been on finding a way to use vlookup or index-match but I haven't been able to make either work how I am intending.

The purpose of all this is to avoid the need of manual data entry when processing a customer order into our manufacturing documentation.

Comment: This attempt does not work:   =IFERROR(INDEX(model_list,MATCH(OrderReport!AI50,model_list,0)),"")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Array Formula:

```
=INDEX(model_list,MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*-"&model_list&"-*",'Sheet1'!A3)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA(model_list))))))
```

Being an array, it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter, instead of Enter when leaving edit mode.

The following picture is only to show it works, I put everything on one page.

[image]

Comment: I tried this, and it returned a value from the "model_list" but it was not the matching value.  In my case the cell with the formula is I35, the order reference is OrderReport!AI52, and the returned value is  LISTS!AR35 within the model_list. The matching cell would have been LISTS!AR9
=INDEX(model_list,MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*-"&model_list&"-*",OrderReport!AI52)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA(model_list))))))

Comment: Did you use the Ctrl-Shift-Enter after putting the formula in the formula bar?  Excel will put `{}` around the formula if you used the Ctrl-Shift-Enter properly.  Click in the formula bar then hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: Tried it again on a single sheet like you, then changed variables into correct locations, and eventually got it to work. Not sure why my first go around was unsuccessful but thank you for the solution!